# Read all messages in MQ at once

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq

I am trying to read messages from MQ all at once by iterating through it. Currently I am only able to read one message at a time. I want to have a counter which will control how many times the loop will get executed or something like a while loop which will terminate when the queue is empty or else will continue reading message.

```
public string ReadMessages()
        {
            MQQueue mqDestination;
            String Readmessage = null;
            QueueManagerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManagername"];
            Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
            properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]);
            properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortNo"]);
            properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Channelname"]);            
            properties.Add(MQC.MQCA_TOPIC_NAME, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"]);

            properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, properties);

            int openOptionsForGet = (MQC.MQSO_CREATE
                                        + (MQC.MQSO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
                                        + (MQC.MQSO_MANAGED
                                        + (MQC.MQSO_NON_DURABLE + MQC.MQMO_NONE))));


            MQGetMessageOptions Gmo;
            MQMessage RetrievedMessage;
            RetrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
            try
            {
                RetrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
                Gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                //Queue Name
                mqDestination = queueManager.AccessQueue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"], openOptionsForGet);
                mqDestination.Get(RetrievedMessage, Gmo);
                string message = RetrievedMessage.ReadString(RetrievedMessage.MessageLength);
                queueManager.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.ReasonCode)
                {
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE:
                        Library.ErrorLogs("error" + "No message available.");
                        break;
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_QUIESCING:
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_STOPPING:
                        Library.ErrorLogs("error" + "Queue Manager Stopping: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManagername"] + "\t" + ex.Message);
                        break;
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_ACTIVE:
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                        Library.ErrorLogs("error" + "Queue Manager not available: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManagername"] + "\t" + ex.Message);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Library.ErrorLogs("error" + " Error reading topic: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"] + "\t" + ex.Message);
                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine("MQException caught. " + mqE.ToString());
                Library.ErrorLogs("error" + ex.Message);
                queueManager.Disconnect();

            }
           return Readmessage;


        }
```

Comment: You call it a topic and use subscription options but later use AccessQueue on `AppSettings["QueueName"]`.  Are you attempting to open a queue and read messages or subscribe to a topic and receive messages?

Answer (score 1):

(1) You cannot get all the messages from a queue at once.  You need to retrieve each message individually.  MQ is not a database.

(2) You have topic code in your sample.  Are you getting messages from a queue or topic.  There is a difference.

Here is a fully functioning CS/.NET/MQ sample program to retrieve all messages on a queue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using IBM.WMQ;

/// <summary> Program Name
/// MQTest72
///
/// Description
/// This C# class will connect to a remote queue manager
/// and get messages from a queue using a managed .NET environment.
///
/// </summary>
/// <author>  Roger Lacroix
/// </author>
namespace MQTest72
{
   class MQTest72
   {
      private Hashtable qMgrProp = null;
      private System.String qManager;
      private System.String inputQName;

      /*
      * The constructor
      */
      public MQTest72()
         : base()
      {
      }

      /// <summary> Make sure the required parameters are present.</summary>
      /// <returns> true/false
      /// </returns>
      private bool allParamsPresent()
      {
         bool b = false;

         if ( (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionName"] != null) &&
              (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"] != null) &&
              (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelName"] != null) &&
              (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QMgrName"] != null) &&
              (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"] != null) )
         {
            try
            {
               System.Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
               b = true;
            }
            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
               b = false;
            }
         }

         return b;
      }

      /// <summary> Extract the configuration applicaiton settings and initialize the MQ variables.</summary>
      /// <param name="args">
      /// </param>
      /// <throws>  IllegalArgumentException </throws>
      private void init(System.String[] args)
      {
         if (allParamsPresent())
         {
            qManager = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QMgrName"];
            inputQName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"];

            qMgrProp = new Hashtable();
            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);

            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionName"]);
            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelName"]);

            try
            {
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, System.Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]));
            }
            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
            }

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"] != null)
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"]);

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"] != null)
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);

            logger("Parameters:");
            logger("  QMgrName ='" + qManager + "'");
            logger("  Queue Name ='" + inputQName + "'");

            logger("Connection values:");
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in qMgrProp)
            {
               logger("  " + de.Key + " = '" + de.Value + "'");
            }
         }
         else
         {
            throw new System.ArgumentException();
         }
      }

      /// <summary> Connect, open queue, retrieve all messages, close queue and disconnect.</summary>
      /// <throws>  MQException </throws>
      private void handleIt()
      {
         MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
         MQQueue inQ = null;
         int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

         try
         {
            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, qMgrProp);
            logger("MQTest72 successfully connected to " + qManager);

            inQ = qMgr.AccessQueue(inputQName, openOptions);
            logger("MQTest72 successfully opened " + inputQName);

            retrieveAll(inQ);
         }
         catch (MQException mqex)
         {
            logger("MQTest72 CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
         }
         catch (System.IO.IOException ioex)
         {
            logger("MQTest72 ioex=" + ioex);
         }
         finally
         {
            try
            {
                if (inQ != null)
                {
                    inQ.Close();
                    logger("MQTest72 closed: " + inputQName);
                }
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
                logger("MQTest72 CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
            }

            try
            {
                if (qMgr != null)
                {
                    qMgr.Disconnect();
                    logger("MQTest72 disconnected from " + qManager);
                }
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
                logger("MQTest72 CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
            }
         }
      }

      /// <summary> Retrieve all messages from a queue or until a 'QUIT' message is received.</summary>
      /// <param name="inQ">
      /// </param>
      private void retrieveAll(MQQueue inQ)
      {
         bool flag = true;
         MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
         gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
         MQMessage msg = null;

         while (flag)
         {
            try
            {
               msg = new MQMessage();
               inQ.Get(msg, gmo);
               if (msg.Feedback == MQC.MQFB_QUIT)
               {
                  flag = false;
                  logger("received quit message - exiting loop");
               }
               else
                  logger("Message Data: " + msg.ReadString(msg.MessageLength));
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
               logger("CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
               if (mqex.Reason == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)
               {
                  // no meesage - life is good
                  flag = false;
                  logger("no more meesages - exiting loop");
               }
               else
               {
                  flag = false;  // severe error - time to exit
               }
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioex)
            {
               logger("ioex=" + ioex);
            }
         }
      }

      /// <summary> Output the log message to stdio.</summary>
      /// <param name="data">
      /// </param>
      private void logger(String data)
      {
         DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
         System.Console.Out.WriteLine(myDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " " + this.GetType().Name + ": " + data);
      }

      /// <summary> main line</summary>
      /// <param name="args">
      /// </param>
      //        [STAThread]
      public static void Main(System.String[] args)
      {
         MQTest72 mqt = new MQTest72();

         try
         {
            mqt.init(args);
            mqt.handleIt();
         }
         catch (System.ArgumentException e)
         {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Usage: MQTest72 -h host -p port -c channel -m QueueManagerName -q QueueName [-u userID] [-x passwd]");
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
         }

         System.Environment.Exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code to read the messages in loop as below. Also note that the options you have used for opening queue are not correct.

```
public string ReadMessages()
        {
            MQQueue mqDestination;
            String Readmessage = null;
            QueueManagerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManagername"];
            Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
            properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]);
            properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortNo"]);
            properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Channelname"]);            
            properties.Add(MQC.MQCA_TOPIC_NAME, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"]);

            properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);

            try
            {
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, properties);

            int openOptionsForGet = MQC.MQOO_INPUT + MQC.MQSO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

                //Queue Name
                mqDestination = queueManager.AccessQueue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"],openOptionsForGet);


//Read messages with a wait of 30 seconds. Break out of the loop when there are no messages (MQRC 2033) or any other reason code is received.
                while (true) {
                  try {
                    MQGetMessageOptions Gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                    Gmo.WaitInterval = 30
                    Gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;
                    MQMessage RetrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
                    mqDestination.Get(RetrievedMessage, Gmo);
                    string message = RetrievedMessage.ReadString(RetrievedMessage.MessageLength);
                } catch(MQException ex) {
                       // Display the exception and break;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                mqDestination.Close();
                queueManager.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.ReasonCode)
                {
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE:
                        Library.ErrorLogs("error" + "No message available.");
                        break;
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_QUIESCING:
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_STOPPING:
                        Library.ErrorLogs("error" + "Queue Manager Stopping: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManagername"] + "\t" + ex.Message);
                        break;
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_ACTIVE:
                    case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                        Library.ErrorLogs("error" + "Queue Manager not available: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManagername"] + "\t" + ex.Message);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Library.ErrorLogs("error" + " Error reading topic: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"] + "\t" + ex.Message);
                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine("MQException caught. " + mqE.ToString());
                Library.ErrorLogs("error" + ex.Message);
                queueManager.Disconnect();

            }
           return Readmessage;


        }
```

Comment: I would definitely not make `MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE` look like an error. It is highly likely a normal case that no messages are available after 30 seconds wait time.